# How to avoid inserting duplicate entries when adding values via a sqlalchemy relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, table-relationships

Let's assume we have two tables in a many to many relationship as shown below:

```
class User(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'user'
  uid = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
  languages = db.relationship('Language', lazy='dynamic',
                              secondary='user_language')

class UserLanguage(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'user_language'
  __tableargs__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('uid', 'lid', name='user_language_ff'),)

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  uid = db.Column(db.String(80), db.ForeignKey('user.uid'))
  lid = db.Column(db.String(80), db.ForeignKey('language.lid'))

class Language(db.Model):
  lid = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
  language_name = db.Column(db.String(30))
```

Now in the python shell:

```
In [4]: user = User.query.all()[0]

In [11]: user.languages = [Language('1', 'English')]

In [12]: db.session.commit()

In [13]: user2 = User.query.all()[1]

In [14]: user2.languages = [Language('1', 'English')]

In [15]: db.session.commit()

IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) column lid is not unique u'INSERT INTO language (lid, language_name) VALUES (?, ?)' ('1', 'English')
```

How can I let the relationship know that it should ignore duplicates and not break the unique constraint for the Language table? Of course, I could insert each language separately and check if the entry already exists in the table beforehand, but then much of the benefit offered by sqlalchemy relationships is gone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy wiki has a [collection of examples](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes), one of which is how you might [check uniqueness of instances](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject).

The examples are a bit convoluted though.  Basically, create a classmethod `get_unique` as an alternate constructor, which will first check a session cache, then try a query for existing instances, then finally create a new instance.  Then call `Language.get_unique(id, name)`  instead of `Language(id, name)`.

I've written a [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20834991/400617) in response to OP's bounty on another question.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest to read [Association Proxy: Simplifying Association Objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects). In this case your code would translate into something like below:

```
# NEW: need this function to auto-generate the PK for newly created Language
# here using uuid, but could be any generator
def _newid():
    import uuid
    return str(uuid.uuid4())

def _language_find_or_create(language_name):
    language = Language.query.filter_by(language_name=language_name).first()
    return language or Language(language_name=language_name)


class User(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'user'
  uid = Column(String(80), primary_key=True)
  languages = relationship('Language', lazy='dynamic',
                              secondary='user_language')

  # proxy the 'language_name' attribute from the 'languages' relationship
  langs = association_proxy('languages', 'language_name',
            creator=_language_find_or_create,
            )

class UserLanguage(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'user_language'
  __tableargs__ = (UniqueConstraint('uid', 'lid', name='user_language_ff'),)

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  uid = Column(String(80), ForeignKey('user.uid'))
  lid = Column(String(80), ForeignKey('language.lid'))

class Language(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'language'
  # NEW: added a *default* here; replace with your implementation
  lid = Column(String(80), primary_key=True, default=_newid)
  language_name = Column(String(30))

# test code
user = User(uid="user-1")
# NEW: add languages using association_proxy property
user.langs.append("English")
user.langs.append("Spanish")
session.add(user)
session.commit()

user2 = User(uid="user-2")
user2.langs.append("English") # this will not create a new Language row...
user2.langs.append("German")
session.add(user2)
session.commit()
```

Comment: `AttributeError: type object 'Language' has no attribute 'query'`

Comment: The OP was using `flask-sqlalchemy` which adds this to each model. You can replace it with `session.query(Language)`.

Comment: but a query doesn't solve OP's issue, which --in the case of many subsequent insertions, by setting `user.languages` to a collection of `Language` objects and committing -- would be slowed significantly for additions to the database of many users. Is there a solution that creates if not exists (upsert in PostgresQL) more efficiently than checking each time whether it exists? Maybe keep a `dict()` alongside the class of current values if the the list is like, a few hundred strings?